Looking for freely available primary source of all St. Philip Neri's Maxims and Sayings, preferably in English
According to the publisher description Oxford Oratory's 2024 edition of The Maxims and Saying of St. Philip Neri:

A collection of the spiritual advice of St Philip Neri, with a maxim for every day of the year. This collection was first prepared in Turin and translated into English by Fr Faber of the London Oratory in 1847. Fr Faber’s English edition is here reprinted by the Fathers of the Oxford Oratory in 2024.

Not counting that publication, I have not been able to find any archived old books which contain these sayings (at least in English). What seems to be readily available are Internet postings, such as Wikisource and Liturgia Latina.
QUESTION: Does anyone know where I may access a book which publishes these maxims and sayings (for each day of the year) dating from either the 19th century or the early twentieth century?

It's Ricordi e Dette di San Filippo Neri in .

@Geremia Would you know where I can locate an original (or close to it) translation into English by Fr. F. W. Faber---Not what is generally found on the internet, but a photocopy of something which has actually appeared in print? Many thanks.
